# findViewById returning null (TextView)

Tags: java, android, textview

I have searched on google as well as StackOverflow. 
But none of the solutions fixed my problem.
findViewById is returning null when it is there in onCreate .
But, when i change it to onClick function, it works fine.
please help me. i am beginner to android programming.

my MainFunction.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
    final TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText("hi world.");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

My fragment_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="onClick" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="108dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: You are using `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and the `textView1` is in `fragment_main`. Move the code to your `Fragment`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    TextView t = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText("hi world.");
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `TextView` is in fragment (`fragment_main.xml`) and you are looking into `R.layout.activity_main`.So better to write that `findViewById` in your `Fragment` which is `PlaceholderFragment`.Or you can use `Inflater` to get your `fragment_layout` and than use `view.findViewById` to get your `TextView`.